# Calling function with "if" inside a "for" loop in django not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

{% if "Anonymous" == i.verifiedUser %}  doesnt seem to work despite i.verifiedUser being valid. I can write anything else where "i.verifiedUser" is, and it will still show the same. How can i fix this?

index.html:

```
<div class="comments">
  {% for i in comment %}
    {% if "Anonymous" == i.verifiedUser %}
    <small>{{i.verifiedUser}}</small>
    {% else %}
    <small class="verifiedUser">{{i.verifiedUser}}</small>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def question(request, questionId):
    question = Qna.objects.get(id=questionId)
    comment = Comment.objects.filter(questionId=questionId).order_by('-timestamp')

    otherQuestions = Qna.objects.all()[:10]
    return render(request, 'index/question.html', {'question':question, 'comment':comment, 'otherQuestions':otherQuestions})
```

Comment: what is that verifiedUser mean?

Comment: You need to show at least your comment model and perhaps the view if it changes its representation.

Comment: You are telling that i.verifiedUser should be equal to a string "Anonymous". Is that right? The expected output is very confusing, as both conditions outputs almost the same result. Btw, there is a django function that should do what you are trying to achieve {% if user.is_authenticated %} it is less error prone than a custom made one.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to make i.verifiedUser equal to "Anonymous". I have used class="verifiedUser" and changed the text color in CSS, so the output makes sense as they show different things. verifiedUser just shows the "user" who made the comment, which is not really a registered user but more like a flair on reddit. By default all comments are from "anonymous", but admins can choose to label comments to be from an official source.

Comment: I just added the views.py